# Talend ETL jobs calling through Web Service

Tags: sql, oracle, talend

Our requirement is to call "Talend ETL job" from another application sources like Salesforce, Jira & others. 
Can someone please guide me for process steps needs to be used for calling "Talend ETL job" through "Web Service" technique.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can build your job as a web service, see [here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforMDMUserGuide61EN/5.2.2+How+to+build+Jobs#id-5.2.2HowtobuildJobs-HowtobuildaJobasaWebservice)

To pass parameters to your job, you need to declare your context variable the assign its values like this:

```
http://localhost:8080//export_job/services/export_job3?method=runJob&arg1=--context_param%20FirstName=F&arg2=--context_param%20LastName=L
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response ... Yes, I follow the steps & Webservice working as per expectation ... Thanks again :) :)   ....  Here I have one more query onto this -> Now we would like to pass Parameters from this web service !! Can you please share your thoughts onto this?   Thanks in advance